# How to add colors to violinplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I am preparing violin plots with the data I have.

What I want to do is to give a distinct color, like a rainbow colormap, to my plots in the violin plot.
I have something running with the exact same color, but I want to introduce some variation.

```
vp1 = violinplot(y1, x1, points=20, widths=0.9, showmeans=True, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)
for pc in vp1['bodies']:
    pc.set_facecolor('red')
    pc.set_edgecolor('black')
vp1['cmeans'].set_color('black')
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of colors:

```
vp1 = violinplot(y1, x1, points=20, widths=0.9, showmeans=True, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violat"]
len_colors = len(colors)
i = 0
for pc in vp1['bodies']:
    pc.set_facecolor(colors[i])
    pc.set_edgecolor('black')
    i += 1
    if i == len_colors:
        i = 0
vp1['cmeans'].set_color('black')
```

Explanation:

`i = 0` sets the index for the `colors` to `0`, and after each use of a color, increment the variable by `1`, so that the next color will be the next color in the list.

If `i` got incremented to the point where it's equal to the length of `colors`, set its value back to `0`.

---

**If you want each color to be completely random and different, you can use the [`random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) method from the built-in [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module:**

```
from random import random

# Your code
vp1 = violinplot(y1, x1, points=20, widths=0.9, showmeans=True, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)
for pc in vp1['bodies']:
    pc.set_facecolor((random(), random(), random()))
    pc.set_edgecolor('black')
vp1['cmeans'].set_color('black')
```

Comment: this is great! however, if I have 100s of columns of data, and I want them to have distinct colors, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
def randomColor():
  r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
  color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r(), r(), r())
  return color    

vp1 = violinplot(y1, x1, points=20, widths=0.9, showmeans=True, showextrema=False, showmedians=False)
    for pc in vp1['bodies']:
        pc.set_facecolor(randomColor())
        pc.set_edgecolor('black')
    vp1['cmeans'].set_color('black')
```

You can use this if you have 100s of columns. The function `randomColor()` generates a random `hex` value and gives a random color every iteration.